# Inconsistency of solutions of equivalences of inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I apologize in advance if this question is too easy. I am dealing with a contest math problem (on the easy side), that requires me to prove or disprove:

$$\exists a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}. 4a(1-b) > 1 \wedge 4b(1-c) > 1 \wedge 4c(1-d) > 1 \wedge 4d(1-a) > 1$$

Now the solution is to give a case where this is true, showing the existence of (a,b,c,d), such as $a=2$, $b=-2$ , $c=3$, $d=-1$, however I am not happy with doing guesswork and would like to come up with some sort of a rule for how to pick the numbers.

I came up with the following equivalences of inequalities, resulting in an easily readable rules in set-builder notation. Here it is:

$1)\quad 4a(1-b)+4b(1-c)+4c(1-d)+4d(1-a) > 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \quad \text{Add the inequalities together}$ 
$2) \quad 4a-4ab+4b-4bc+4c-4cd+4d-4da > 4 \quad \text{Distributivity}$ 
$3) \quad (a-ab+b-bc+c-cd+d-da) > \frac{4}{4} \quad \text{Distributivity and dividing}$ 
$4) \quad -a(b+d)-c(b+d)+(a+c)+(b+d) > 1 \quad \text{More distributivity}$ 
$5) \quad -(a+c)(b+d)+(a+c)+(b+d) > 1 \quad \text{Distributivity}$ 
$6) \quad (a+c)(-(b+d)+1)+(b+d) > 1 \quad \text{Distributivity again}$ 
$7) \quad (a+c)(1-(b+d)) > 1-(b+d) \quad \text{Carry over a term}$

$\quad$ Now we split cases: 
$\quad$ a) If $1-(b+d) > 0$ then the inequality sign doesn't change when we divide by it. We can also write an equivalent form $1 > (b+d).$

$8) \quad a+c > \frac{1-(b+d)}{1-(b+d)} \Leftrightarrow a + c > 1$ 
Thus one condition is: $\{(a,b,c,d) | (a+c) > 1 > (b+d)\}$

$\quad$ b) If $1-(b+d) < 0$ then the inequality sign changes when we divide by it. We can also write an equivalent form $1 < (b+d).$

$9) \quad a+c < \frac{1-(b+d)}{1-(b+d)} \Leftrightarrow a + c < 1$ 
Thus another condition is: $\{(a,b,c,d) | (a+c) < 1 < (b+d)\}$

$\quad$ c) If $1-(b+d) = 0$  then:

$10) \quad (a+c) \cdot 0 < 0 $ Here, there is no solution, so we could add the $1 -(b+d) \neq 0$ to our other conditions, but it's already satisfied.

$$\{(a,b,c,d) | ((a+c) > 1 > (b+d)) \vee ((b+d) > 1 > (a+c)) \}$$

**What I'm missing is the condition, that $a, b, c, d \neq 0$, which is easily readable from the initial inequalities, such as: $4a(1-b) > 1$. Also the condition $a, b, c, d \neq 1$ is missing.**

My question then would be, how do we rigorously determine that $a,b,c,d \neq 0$ from one of the later inequalities, such as $8)$ or $9)$, which are equivalent to the initial problem statement inequalities? Without having to glue together the conditions - some from the initial inequalities and some from the later inequalities? Or is gluing together the solutions the only option? That doesn't seem very algebraic or rigorous to me.

Comment: tl;dr. I am pretty sure you loose the condition $a, b, c, d \neq 0$ in the moment when you add the four inequalities together.

Comment: @KurtG. Oh, so when adding inequalities some information is "lost" and it doesn't actually yield a strict equivalence? Am I interpreting your comment correctly? I'll look into that. How could I have missed that.

Comment: You interprete my comment correctly. Take the two simplest inequalities you can think of to see that $x>1\wedge y>1$ implies but is not equvalent to $x+y>1+1\,.$

Comment: Taking $c=a$ and $d=b$, we have only $4a(1-b)>1$ and $4b(1-a)>1$. Then, taking $b=-a$ gives $a(a+1)>1/4$ and $a(a-1)>1/4$, which is easy.

Comment: @mathlove Thank you for commenting. I am still slightly confused as to how to determine the broadest possible solution set. $\{(a,b,c,d) | c=a \wedge d = b \wedge b = -a \wedge a(a+1) > \frac{1}{4} \wedge a(a-1) > \frac{1}{4} \}$ doesn't seem to be that set, as c and a can differ, as per my example at the start. Is the only solution to glue things together from, say, the initial inequalities and 8) and 9)? How would one then know that you're done with the conditions and that you haven't missed any? I apologize if my question is too silly.

Comment: I was not trying to determine the broadest possible solution set. What I showed is one way to pick the numbers without doing guesswork because all we have to do is to show one example. Also, as Kurt G suggested, your inequality in 1) is not equivalent to the initial four inequalities.

Comment: @mathlove Ah, I see. It's an elegant solution without solving the inequality for all solutions. And I agree, 8) and 9) might have solutions that don't necessarily belong to the initial question. That's what I was trying to restrict, as I still believe some "info" is "preserved" in 8) and 9), as they helped me find one of the possible solutions. But I can't find an algebraic explanation. I'll ponder on it some more. Thanks for the explaining!